# Importing Gtk typelib for Python on KDE

Tags: python, linux, import, gtk, kde-plasma

I have written a GUI application in python making use of Gtk.
Unfortunately I had to move to a new OS and absolutely have to use its KDE desktop.

Now python can not import any of the submodules from gi.repository,
despite python-gi being installed and up to date:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib
```

It seems to be a general problem on Linux, that any submodule references of
gi.repository can not be resolved but strangely enough the python GUI was
still executable and ran flawlessly on all Gnome systems (Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Linux Mint) I tested it on.

Not so on KDE.
Running the code yields the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder/Program.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk
```

I am a bit lost how to overcome this error.
I think I have to install some Gtk system packages/typelib, but which?

Could not find anything on the web.

Any suggestions are warmly welcome!

Info:
I am running on Debian Wheezy with KDE.

Comment: Which distribution are you running this on? The answer differs per distribution; for instance, on Debian/Ubuntu-based systems, you have to install `gir1.2-gtk-[23].0` depending on which GTK+ version you want to target as well as the appropriate `libgtk*-dev` for that version. (At least I think; I'm not sure if they both need to be installed for Python or not...;  this is why this is a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: Thanks. I run on Debian Wheezy with KDE.

Comment: OK, I installed gir1.2-gtk3.0 via apt. Now this worked in so far as now a Gtk version is recognized. Unfortuately I get a gi._glib.GError: XXX_GUI.glade: required gtk+ version 3.10, current version is 3.4. Will open a new thread to ask for assistance on that issue. Make an answer to this threads question and I accept it.

Comment: New thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077704/gtk-version-error-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer differs per distribution; for instance, on Debian/Ubuntu-based systems, you have to install `gir1.2-gtk-[23].0` depending on which GTK+ version you want to target as well as the appropriate `libgtk*-dev` for that version. (At least I think; I'm not sure if they both need to be installed for Python or not...).