# Gtk+ Version Error on Linux

Tags: python, linux, debian, gtk3

I run a python application which uses a glade builder file for its GUI.
I recently migrated to a KDE desktop (Debian Wheezy). After installing the Gtk bindings with apt 
(gir1.2-gtk-3.0) I tried to following error message when starting the Python
code:

```
gi._glib.GError: XXX.glade: required gtk+ version 3.10, current version is 3.4
```

How could I best solve this?

Do I need to downgrade Gtk from 3.4 to 3.1? And if yes how do I do that? 
How do I find version 3.10 in the repositories?

Or is something wrongly configured? Maybe the Gtk version being fixed in the
glade file which I imported from a different system, whose Gtk version might
have been different (do not remember)?

Or any other suggestions?

I do not think source code is helpful in this matter, as the problem most likely is located outside of it, nonetheless some extract from it:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib

wTree = Gtk.Builder()

class Test_GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("XXX.glade")
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("MainScreen")
        self.window.show_all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the solution was to recompile the .glade builder file.
Somehow the version conflict was that the glade file was created on
a different system than it got used at.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us wich program you try to use ? Can you Modify the source code to fit with your Gtk version ? Does it work ?

The upgrade from Gtk 3.4 to 3.10 is not possible (with aptitude or apt-get); Gtk 3.10 can't be found in the official repository of debian (correct me if i'm wrong), see this [link](https://www.0d.be/debian/debian-gnome-3.10-status.html)
However you can install a later unstable version, see this [link](https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gtk+3.0.html) (It's not recommand too).

Comment: Thanks. How would I modify my source code to fit the Gtk version? I would not like to go back to Gtk 2.0 to then use PyGtk.

Comment: Wich program do you try to use ? 
PyGtk become PyGObject (PyGI) for GTK3+. If you want use GTK2+ you can download PyGtk and install it from this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGTK/2.7.2) for Python 2.7

Comment: As I wrote. I do not want to use gtk/PyGtk, but Gtk3/+.